# Angular 7 route on click after http-request got full performed

Tags: angular, httprequest, angular-routing, angular-http

I have a List of entries and when I click into one list I get into a more detailed view of the item. Now this view load via http-Request (which is taking a little longer than the routing from page to page). So let's say I have the following code:

For the destination-page:

```
 projectNumber: string = '';

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private logger: LoggerService,
    private projectReceiverService: ProjectReceiverService
  ) {
    this.initProjectDataFromProjectNumber(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('projectNum'));
  }

  initProjectDataFromProjectNumber(projectNumber: string) {
    let project = this.projectReceiverService.getProjectByNumber(projectNumber); 
    this.projectNumber = projectNumber; //getProjectNumber => results in error
  }
```

For the service:

```
 getProjectByNumber(projectNumber: string): Project {
 let project: Project; 
 this.http.get(httpBaseUrl + "/project/getProject/" + projectNumber, httpOptions).subscribe((data) => {
  this.logger.info("Received data, processing...");
  project = data['projectDto'];
},
(error) => {
  this.logger.error("Error when receiving project.");
  this.logger.error(error.message);
});;
 return project;
}
```

And for the previous page (where I click the item):

```
 projectClicked(projectNumber: string) {
    this.routeTo('projects/' + projectNumber);
  }
```

Now it'd be great if I could somehow manage to route after the http-request has fully successed (since I could e.g. pass the project-object directly when routing and also I wouldn't hit struggles with displaying some data that might not yet be loaded on the detailed-page). How could I do that? I thought about loading it on the previous side before something gets clicked but that'd be hell of an overload to previously load all details for every item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily with route resolver.

It goes like this. In your route config, you give your route path, component, and a `resolver`.

```
const routes = [{
  path: 'projects/:projectNumber',
  component: DestinationComponent,
  resolve: {
    project: ProjectResolver
  },
}];
```

Now you have to put this route in the module, and *provide the resolver you mentioned*. E.g. like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [ProjectResolver],
})
export class ProjectDetailsModule {}
```

But what is this ProjectResolver? It is simply an injectable class implementing Angular's Resolve interface, which on it's `resolve()` method gives back the data, either as data, Promise or Observable. Looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
// You will also need your service
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectResolver implements Resolve {
  // Inject it with where the data comes from
  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {}

  // Now implement the resolve interface. Angular will give you the route,
  // from which you can read the parameter.
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Project> {
    const projectNumber = route.snapshot.params['projectNumber'];
    return this.projectService.getProjectByNumber(projectNumber);
  }
}
```

Now, we have to fix a little your service - the http method is usually async, so you have to return the observable instead:

```
// I'll change the return type, from Project, to Obsevable<Project>
getProjectByNumber(projectNumber: string): Observable<Project> {
  return this.http.get(`${ httpBaseUrl }/project/getProject/${ projectNumber }`,  httpOptions)
    // Instead of subscribe, you'll use a pipe, to map. So that others can actually subscribe (in our case the Angular router)
    .pipe(
      map(data => {
        this.logger.info("Received data, processing...");
        project = data['projectDto'];
        return project;

        // This whole `map(...)` part could have been a one-liner:
        // map(data => data.projectDto)
        // so alltogether:
        // this.http.get().pipe( map(data => data.projectDto), catchError(this.logger.error));
    },
    catchError(err => this.logger.error('Error getting project:', err.message)),
  );
}
```

Only one thing left. How do we get the data once in the component? From the route, again.

```
// in the component
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(project => this.project = project);
  // or something like this for immediate value:
  // this.data = this.route.snapshot.data;
}
```

Note that this will hold your page in "loading" until the data is actually back. If you wanna fetch the data in parallel, that is a different answer, but can also be done.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for this answer! Just to clarify this for me: You mentioned a `ProjectDetailsModule` (where I need to add the resolver). My `ProjectDetail` is a component and I am not having a module for it - where would I need to add this? In my `app.module.ts`?    Edit: If I would like to fetch the data in parallel, what'd I need to do there? I know this is a different question, but could you give me a keyword or something to look for?

Comment: Few questions :) 1. ProjectDetailsModule is just a routing module that sets up the route for this particular thing. If you don't use modules (you should, it's easy and helps a lot in the long run), then just add this route in all your other app routes - wherever your `RouterModule.forRoot(...)` is. 2) Parallel requests - parallel to what? Two http requests in parallel? Look into forkJoin. Or e.g. this StackBlitz of mine I've just created for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parallel-http-requests?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for that, I will have a look at it! :) So that means - basically - I should create a module for each component?